# Mini CD in Mac Mini

Tags: mac-mini

How does one get a mini CD out of a Mac Mini? It got stuck in there pretty deep and I'm scared to take the drive and shake it. I tried getting it out by "levering" w/ a pen clip but that didn't help. Help me please!

Comment: what MrU said - or a credit card with double-sided tape, or even a post-it note.  On the subject of notes… please note you can't put mini CDs in a slot-loader. afaik, only the Wii is designed to take them.

Answer (score 1):

Tweezers? I use tweezers often in our car, which the cd player's eject function won't work.

But since yours is so "deep" down, can you still see it? If not, well, *slim* tweezers?
If you can still see it, you should be able to use the tweezers.

**-------------------------------**

Another way is maybe a hook fashioned out of a plastic sheet? take a slim but sturdy sheet, cut it so that it fits into the drive, and fold a small fold along one end. The fold will act like a hook and grab onto the drive.

Insert the plastic folded end first, facing down. try to get the plastic on top of the disc so the fold slides over the top and unfold behind it. The fold should "catch" the disc and then you can pull it out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: next time, use a designated mini cd adapter - They look like normal sized discs with a slot in the middle to hold the mini cd in place